# Checking reputation points on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, reputation, stack-exchange

I am a newbie here, and the more I try to interact here, it asks me to gain some reputation.
How do you check your reputation points on Stack Exchange?

Comment: You don't seem to have any account besides at Meta Stack Exchange. To check your reputation you would go to your [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/384482/user384482?tab=topactivity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) and click on your profile button on top-right corner of the page.

Then, it will take you to your profile summary page where you see options like

> summary, answers, questions, ......

Here in this list you can find **"reputation"**.

Click on it, and you can see your reputation.

Comment: I will add "*meta stock exchange*" to [my list](http://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_2018-02-13.html) (joining 12 others)...

Comment: @PeterMortensen i am new to this platform. I don't get "my list" mentioned above. Could you please explain?

Comment: What do you mean by *"I don't get"*? Have you opened the link?